# Capybara ambiguous match errors

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

The project is a reboot of the original, and I am trying to get to grips with the various gems - the rails composer does a brilliant job of everything but me gaining understanding of what is going on.

I am getting this Capybara error that is tied to the signup code (I have several specs using the call, but have only included one of them here as they all call the same helper).

```
 Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching field "Password"
```

I have looked on StackOverflow (several times), and used the power of Messr Google - who mainly suggests I look here.

At first I thought it was to do with having a mismatch of

```
fill_in 'Email', with: email
```

and

```
fill_in 'Email', :with => email
```

but neither seems to make a difference.

From reading the documentation (I know: hangs head in shame) at [rubydoc.info capybara fill-in](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions:fill_in) , the fill-in takes a locator and an options array.

My understanding is that `fill_in 'Password', with: password` would match the `Password` locator, which is the `id="user_password"` part of the html. I don't see any others on the page, so am now reaching out for help.

All my code is on the SO001 branch of my project[Github project branch to match this question](https://github.com/nstoker/rocktrack/blob/feature/SO001/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb).

sign_up_spec.rb

```
feature 'Sign Up', :devise do
  # Scenario: Visitor can sign up with valid email address and password
  #   Given I am not signed in
  #   When I sign up with a valid email address and password
  #   Then I see a successful sign up message
  scenario 'visitor can sign up with valid email address and password' do
    sign_up_with('test@example.com', 'please123', 'please123')
    txts = [I18n.t( 'devise.registrations.signed_up'), I18n.t( 'devise.registrations.signed_up_but_unconfirmed')]
    expect(page).to have_content(/.*#{txts[0]}.*|.*#{txts[1]}.*/)
  end
    # ... others snipped for space
end
```

spec/support/helpers/session_helpers.rb

```
module Features
  module SessionHelpers
    def sign_up_with(email, password, confirmation)
      visit new_user_registration_path
      save_and_open_page
      fill_in 'Email', with: email
      fill_in 'Password', with: password
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', :with => confirmation
      click_button 'Sign up'
    end

    def signin(email, password)
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: email
      fill_in 'Password', with: password
      click_button 'Sign in'
    end
  end
end
```

The devise new.html.erb code is

### Sign up

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The form part of the html has

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />


  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="form-group email required user_email">
        <label class="control-label email required" for="user_email">
            <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Email
        </label>
        <input class="form-control string email required" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" aria-required="true" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group password required user_password">
        <label class="control-label password required" for="user_password">
            <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
            Password</label>
        <input class="form-control password required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
        <p class="help-block">6 characters minimum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group password required user_password_confirmation">
        <label class="control-label password required" for="user_password_confirmation">
            <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
            Password confirmation
        </label>
        <input class="form-control password required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-default" data-disable-with="Sign up" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented, Capybara's `fill_in` will match an element on either its id or name attributes, or on the text of an associated label element.  The attribute matches need to be exact and the text of an associated label element may be an exact or substring match depending on the setting of a few options.

In the current versions of Capybara, `Capybara.exact` defaults to :smart which when looking for an associated label text match will first attempt for an exact match, and if none is found will attempt for a substring match.  In your case the label text of two of your fields are `*Password` and `*Password confirmation` which when checked for an exact match with `Password` fail, and when checked with a substring match both match - hence the "Ambiguous match" error since more that one element matched.

To fix this (while still using `fill_in`) you could do any of the following

```
fill_in '*Password', with: password # will match exactly on one elements label text

find('div.user_password').fill_in 'Password' with: password # scope fill_in so substring match is unique

fill_in 'user_password', with: password # match on id attribute

fill_in 'user[password]', with: password # match on name attribute
```